# Multipurpose search in sql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to search based on multiple values, but in SQL I don't know how to search based on the second value when one of these values is empty.
Can anyone help me?

This is the SQL that I reached, but I didn't get an answer

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_homes WHERE title LIKE '%$title%' AND city='$city' AND type_home='$type'";
```

Comment: `where (col1 = p1 or p1 is null) and (col2 = p2 or p2 is null) etc`

Comment: _"when one of these values is empty"_ - empty _where_ - in the database column, or in your search parameters?

Answer (score -1):

if title/city/type has a value, add to the query

```php
$and = "";

if ($title){
   $and .= " AND title LIKE '%$title%'";
}

if ($city){
   $and .= " AND city LIKE '%$city%'";
}

if ($type){
   $and .= " AND type_home LIKE '%$type%'";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_homes WHERE 1=1 $and";
```

Comment: NP. For the future, query stuff is better handle with abstractions, most common is ORM that is present in all major PHP frameworks. 
For example Laravel has Eloquent ORM, Wordpress has $wpdb class, etc. All of this are abstractions that simplify working with a relational database like mysql.